# Divisibility of a number of the form $3^{n}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions

If we have a number of the form $3^{n}-1$, how can we know in general what is the greatest power of $2$ that can divide it if we only know the value of $n$ without having to find the value of $3^{n}-1$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Surround mathematical expressions with \$s.   It depends if $n$ is odd or even

Comment: For $n$ odd the greatest power is $2^1$. For a general answer see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29828/greatest-power-of-two-dividing-an-integer). On this site it has been shown at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372512/expression-for-the-highest-power-of-2-dividing-3a-left2b-1-right-1?rq=1), take $b=1$.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $3^n-1=2(3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\cdots+3^2+3+1)$ with the quantity in parentheses being odd

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A090740](https://oeis.org/A090740).

Comment: If $n = 2^e m$ with $m$ odd and $e \ge 1$, the greatest power is $2^{e+2}$.

Comment: $3^{n-1}\ne3^n-1$.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3843292/242)

Answer (score 1):

You can usually use the [LTE Lemma](https://imosuisse.ch/smo/skripte/unused/Lifting_the_exponent_EN.pdf) for such problems.

Using the notation used by the provided document you get by **Theorem 4** (even $n$):

$$v_2(3^n-1^n)=v_2(3-1)+v_2(3+1)+v_2(n)-1=v_2(n)+2$$

So you have to know what is the largest $\alpha$ so that $2^\alpha | n$ (also written as $2^\alpha || n$), hence the largest power of $2$ that divides $3^n-1$ is $\alpha+2$.

For odd $n$ we can use the last equation in the summary, since $\gcd(2,n)=1$:

$$v_2(3^n-1)=v_2(3^n+(-1)^n)=v_2(3+(-1))=v_2(2)=1$$
Hence if $2\nmid n$, $2^1$ is the largest power to divide $3^n-1$. To prove this, you can also look the the factorisation of the expansion and counting how many of powers of $3$ you have (which is odd).

Proofs are also provided in the document.

Comment: hi, could you give me the answer in spanish please?.

Comment: Sorry, never learned spanish...
Maybe you can use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) or [DeepL](https://deepl.com)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: It should be noted that this applies when n is even.

Comment: I have extended the answer for odd n. It is some time since I used LTE, hence I forgot it is only for even n.