# Divisibility of $\frac{3^n - 1}{2}$ by $2^k$

Tags: divisibility

I would like to find the greatest k such that $p=\frac{3^n - 1}{2}$ is divisible by $2^k$.

Since $p$ is the repunit number in base 3 it is already clear that if $n$ is even, $p$ would be divisible by 4 (since we could write $p/2 = 2020...202$ in base 3).

Thus, $p/4 = 1010...101$ which is divisible by 8 only if there is an even number of $1$ wich is equivalent to $n$ being divisible by 4.

Starting from here the pattern gets longer and longer, and I'm not able to generalize for any given $k$. Would someone have an idea?

Comment: Are you trying to find, in terms of $n,$ the greatest $k$ such tht $2^k$ divides $(3^n-1)/2$?

Comment: Yes., that's what I would like to do.

Comment: Then your wording on the question seems misleading, since the phrase "for a given $k$" leads one to conclude you are fixing $k$ first, instead of trying to *determine* the largest such $k$ for a given $n.$

Comment: I edited the question!

Comment: Suggest one more edit in first sentence: replace "such as" by "such that". Otherwise good question, +1.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a clear pattern.  While $8|(3^2 - 1)$ and $16|(3^4 - 1)$, you have that $(3^3 - 1) = (13 \times 2).$  Nor does there seem to be a pattern, where $k$ is even.  That is, $(3^6 - 1)$ is *only* divisible by $8$.  However, if $k$ is even, $k = 2s$, you know that of the two **even** numbers $(3^s - 1), (3^s + 1)$ one of them must be a multiple of $4$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma

Comment: See also the proof in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3843292/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=2^m q$ where $q$ is odd, let $\nu_2(n)=m$.
The answer to the question is $$\nu_2\left(\frac{3^k-1}{2}\right) = \nu_2(k)+\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}$$.
To prove this, first prove that
$$\nu_2\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right) =\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if $k$ is odd}\\
0 & \mbox{ if $k$ is even}\end{cases}.$$
Then use the identity
$$3^{2^m q}-1 = \left(3^{q2^{m-1}}-1\right)\left(3^{q2^{m-1}}+1\right)$$
and induction on $m$.

Comment: This is quite a surprising answer!

Comment: @Vincent Actually it is common to find formulas for the 2-adic valuations of a sequence $a(k)$ in terms of the 2-adic valuation of $k$. You may want to look at the work of Victor Moll and his collaborators on the topic, see for example this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPLOsfL8sCo

Comment: Thank you ! How would you prove that $$\nu_2\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right) =\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if $k$ is odd}\\ 0 & \mbox{ if $k$ is even}\end{cases}.$$
I studied the congruence modulo 8 of $3^k + 1$ to do so but would there be a more elegant way?

Comment: look at the numerator modulo 8