# What is the highest power of $2$ that divides $3^y(2z-1)-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have the following expression:

$$3^y(2z-1)-1$$

Now suppose that $2^x$ is the highest power of two that divides the above. Assume that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all natural numbers. Can I express $x$, in terms of $y$ and $z$?

Comment: This might have something for you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372512/expression-for-the-highest-power-of-2-dividing-3a-left2b-1-right-1?rq=1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no work of your own. You have also posted the same question on math overflow. That's poor stackexchange manners.